# Why is it so popular in many open source code to use #define or typedef aliases for functions or variables built into C?

Tags: c

This is a snippet of code in Tcl

```c
#define TclpSysAlloc(size)      malloc(size)
#define TclpSysFree(ptr)        free(ptr)
#define TclpSysRealloc(ptr, size)   realloc(ptr, size)
```

What good does that do? Or is it a rule that must be followed?

Comment: One of reasons may be debug purpose. You can easily wrap memory management functions for instrumentation. Tcl was developed in 1988, no valgrind, no address sanitizers.

Comment: If you check the Windows counterpart of the Unix header you're looking at, [you'll see something very different there](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/ae7471ec7ee7c03de40fa1c899e56e31ddf7323f/win/tclWinPort.h#L514).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, Due to the portability of the code. In all of the open source projects, developers prefer to use macros instead of raw functions for some parts of code. Macro presents a pre-compile (without additional cost in runtime) opportunity to abstract the functions. Assume we need to use an open-source project that is usable on multiple machines and operating systems. It's obvious that developers have to provide some macros that make their project portable. For example, heap management is an OS-based service, and its functions depend on the operating system generally. You should consider that there are so many machine architectures and operating systems (except Win or Linux), if we suppose embedded systems and real-time operating systems.
Consequently, developers provide a `*_port.h`-like header file to define basic functions according to the target platform and make these functions abstract.
For example, memory allocation in different operating systems:
FreeRTOS:
`pvPortMalloc`
TI SysBIOS:
`Memory_alloc`
Unix:
`malloc`